# Se vuelve a ejecutar mi metodo al recargar la pagina en jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy haciendo un **CRUD** manualmente, no con **jpa** para el mantenimiento de mis tablas **entidades** de mi **Base de datos**, y ya he creado la pagina para agregar datos a la Base de datos , y  en el **beans** tengo un **metodo registrar** que lo mando a llamar en un **actionListener** de un `<h:commandLink/>`.

Mi problema es

> Cuando ingreso por primera vez a la pagina y le doy click al boton y
>   funciona bien, pero si yo recargo la pagina se vuelve a ejecutar la
>   accion y  los datos que habia guardado anteriormente se vuelven a
>   guardar e no quiero que suceda eso?

como hago para saber en mi metodo registrar si la accion se realizo a travez del boton de jsf o del boton del navegador?

**Actualización**

bueno para JDev: no se si jsf trabaja con ajax implicitamente porque yo no estoy ocupando una etiqueta como por ejemplo  para recargar la pagina o actualizar algun componente.
Y para SJuan76, el navegador no me muestra ningun mensaje.
y como dice pablo aqui les cuelgo el codigo:

pagina para crear nuevos datos

```
<h:form>
 <h:messages id="msgCorrecto" infoClass="alert alert-primary"/>

 <h:outputLabel for="txtNombres" value="Nombres:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtNombres" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.nombres}" required="true"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtApellidos" value="Apellidos:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtApellidos" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.apellidos}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Genero:" for="txtGenero"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu id="txtGenero" class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.genero}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="M"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Femenino" itemValue="F"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtFNacimiento" value="F. Nacimiento:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtFNacimiento" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.fechaNacimiento}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Estado civil:"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.estadoCivil}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Soltero/a" itemValue="SOLTERO/A"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Casado/a" itemValue="CASADO/A"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Viudo/a" itemValue="VIUDO/A"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtDireccion" value="Direccion:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtDireccion" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.direccion}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtTelefono" value="Telefono:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtTelefono" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.telefono}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtDUI" value="DUI:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtDUI" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.DUI}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtFAcepto" value="F. Acepto:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtFAcepto" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.fechaAcepto}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Estado civil:"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.estado}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Activo" itemValue="ACTIVO"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inactivo" itemValue="INACTIVO"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:commandButton class="btn btn-info col-lg-3" value="Registrar" actionListener="#{membresiaBean.registrar()}"/>
 </h:form>
```

clase beans:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "membresiaBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MembresiaBean implements Serializable
{    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Membresia membresia = new Membresia();
private List<Membresia> lstMembresia;

public List<Membresia> getLstMembresia() {
    return lstMembresia;
}

public void setLstMembresia(List<Membresia> lstMembresia) {
    this.lstMembresia = lstMembresia;
}

public Membresia getMembresia()
{
    return membresia;
}

public void setMembresia(Membresia membresia) 
{
    this.membresia = membresia;
}

public void registrar()
{
    MembresiaDAO membresiaDAO;

    try 
    {
        membresiaDAO = new MembresiaDAO();
        if (!membresiaDAO.registrar(this.membresia)) 
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(membresiaDAO.getMsgExcepcion()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgCorrecto", new FacesMessage("Miembro registrado correctamente."));                    
        }
   } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

bueno el SessionScoped es porque tengo otra pagina donde he hecho el crud y en la acción 'Actualizar' es un commandLink que me envia a la pagina (con los datos que los toma de un dataTable) para actualizar los datos y si el scoped no es de sesion entonces no me puede redirigir a lo otra pagina.

Comment: Si la llamada no es ajax, al recargar no estas recargando la pagina si no la llamada.

Comment: Cuelga el código

Comment: ¿No te saca el navegador un mensaje de aviso de que volverá a enviar los datos? En todo caso, muestra el código (no una página completa con cien campos, solo el necesario para poder reproducir el comportamiento, mira [mcve]).

Answer (score -1):

de antemano gracias por responder y disculpas por la tardanza.
bueno para JDev: no se si jsf trabaja con ajax implicitamente porque yo no estoy ocupando una etiqueta como por ejemplo  para recargar la pagina o actualizar algun componente.
Y para SJuan76, el navegador no me muestra ningun mensaje.
y como dice pablo aqui les cuelgo el codigo:

pagina para crear nuevos datos

```
<h:form>
 <h:messages id="msgCorrecto" infoClass="alert alert-primary"/>

 <h:outputLabel for="txtNombres" value="Nombres:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtNombres" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.nombres}" required="true"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtApellidos" value="Apellidos:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtApellidos" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.apellidos}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Genero:" for="txtGenero"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu id="txtGenero" class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.genero}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="M"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Femenino" itemValue="F"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtFNacimiento" value="F. Nacimiento:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtFNacimiento" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.fechaNacimiento}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Estado civil:"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.estadoCivil}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Soltero/a" itemValue="SOLTERO/A"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Casado/a" itemValue="CASADO/A"/>
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Viudo/a" itemValue="VIUDO/A"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtDireccion" value="Direccion:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtDireccion" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.direccion}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtTelefono" value="Telefono:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtTelefono" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.telefono}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtDUI" value="DUI:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtDUI" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.DUI}"/>
 <h:outputLabel for="txtFAcepto" value="F. Acepto:"/>
 <h:inputText class="form-control" id="txtFAcepto" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.fechaAcepto}"/>
 <h:outputLabel value="Estado civil:"/>
 <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" value="#{membresiaBean.membresia.estado}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Activo" itemValue="ACTIVO"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Inactivo" itemValue="INACTIVO"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:commandButton class="btn btn-info col-lg-3" value="Registrar" actionListener="#{membresiaBean.registrar()}"/>
 </h:form>
```

clase beans:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "membresiaBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MembresiaBean implements Serializable
{    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Membresia membresia = new Membresia();
private List<Membresia> lstMembresia;

public List<Membresia> getLstMembresia() {
    return lstMembresia;
}

public void setLstMembresia(List<Membresia> lstMembresia) {
    this.lstMembresia = lstMembresia;
}

public Membresia getMembresia()
{
    return membresia;
}

public void setMembresia(Membresia membresia) 
{
    this.membresia = membresia;
}

public void registrar()
{
    MembresiaDAO membresiaDAO;

    try 
    {
        membresiaDAO = new MembresiaDAO();
        if (!membresiaDAO.registrar(this.membresia)) 
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(membresiaDAO.getMsgExcepcion()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgCorrecto", new FacesMessage("Miembro registrado correctamente."));                    
        }
   } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

bueno el SessionScoped es porque tengo otra pagina donde he hecho el crud y en la acción 'Actualizar' es un commandLink que me envia a la pagina (con los datos que los toma de un dataTable) para actualizar los datos y si el scoped no es de sesion entonces no me puede redirigir a lo otra pagina.

Comment: Para editar/actualizar la pregunta, dale al botón de "editar" de tu pregunta, no crees una respuesta. Ya he incorporado yo la información a tú pregunta, por favor elimina esta respuesta.